# Parameters num_leaves and max_leaves yields different results in LightGBM although states as aliases

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-science, lightgbm

LightGBM documentations states max_leaves parameter is just an alias for num_leaves, but results are different based on selection as you can see here with digits dataset.

[image: b]

Comment: lgbm has embedded randomness, no two executions with the same parameters will be the same unless you fix the random seed. your results are not indicative of num_leaves behaving differently than max_leaves